# Can Improved Euler method have more error than Euler Method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

$y'=y-y^2$, $y(0)=0.2$, $h=0.1$. 
That is my problem.What I found out is that there are more error in Improved Euler than Euler.
Is it possible?Or Am I doing wrongly?

Here is my calculation=》  https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0J9H.jpg

Comment: Please type your work in the question itself, instead of putting it in a link. Plus, your picture is sideways.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to get more error. However, as the step size is decreased, the improved Euler gets closer to the correct answer much more quickly

Comment: Do you only consider one step? Did you compute the exact solution and compare the numerical values to it?

Comment: Where do you see the errors in your calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to actually implement the methods and compare them against the exact solution
$$
\phi(t;t_0,x_0)=\frac{x_0}{1-(1-x_0)·(1-\exp(t_0-t))},
$$
for instance with a python script like this one:

```
from math import exp;

def Euler(f,t,x,h):
    return x+h*f(t,x);

def ImprEuler(f,t,x,h):
    k1=h*f(t,x);
    k2=h*f(t+h,x+k1)
    return x+(k1+k2)/2;

def f(t,x):
    return x - x*x;

def phi(t,x0):
    return x0/(1-(1-x0)*(1-exp(-t)))

xE = xIE = x0 = 0.2; 
t = 0;
N = 10
h=1.0/N;

print "\n N=%d, h=%6.3f\n" % (N, h)
for j in range(N+1):
    xt = phi(t,x0);
    print "t=%.2f, x_exact=%8.5f | xEul=%8.5f C_err=%6.3f | xImprE=%8.5f C_err=%6.3f" % ( t, xt, xE, (xE-xt)/h, xIE, (xIE-xt)/h**2 )
    xE = Euler(f,t,xE,h);
    xIE = ImprEuler(f,t,xIE,h);
    t = t+h

xE = xIE = x0 = 0.2; 
t = 0;
N=20;
h=1.0/N;
print "\n N=%d, h=%6.3f\n" % (N, h)
for j in range(N+1):
    xt = phi(t,x0);
    print "t=%.2f, x_exact=%8.5f | xEul=%8.5f C_err=%6.3f | xImprE=%8.5f C_err=%6.3f" % ( t, xt, xE, (xE-xt)/h, xIE,     (xIE-xt)/h**2 )
    xE = Euler(f,t,xE,h);
    xIE = ImprEuler(f,t,xIE,h);
    t = t+h*
```

you would get the following table of results showing that improved Euler is more accurate from the begin on:

```
N=10, h= 0.100

t=0.00, x_exact= 0.20000 | xEul= 0.20000 C_err= 0.000 | xImprE= 0.20000 C_err= 0.000
t=0.10, x_exact= 0.21648 | xEul= 0.21600 C_err=-0.005 | xImprE= 0.21647 C_err=-0.001
t=0.20, x_exact= 0.23392 | xEul= 0.23293 C_err=-0.010 | xImprE= 0.23389 C_err=-0.003
t=0.30, x_exact= 0.25232 | xEul= 0.25080 C_err=-0.015 | xImprE= 0.25227 C_err=-0.004
t=0.40, x_exact= 0.27164 | xEul= 0.26959 C_err=-0.021 | xImprE= 0.27159 C_err=-0.006
t=0.50, x_exact= 0.29188 | xEul= 0.28928 C_err=-0.026 | xImprE= 0.29180 C_err=-0.007
t=0.60, x_exact= 0.31296 | xEul= 0.30984 C_err=-0.031 | xImprE= 0.31288 C_err=-0.009
t=0.70, x_exact= 0.33486 | xEul= 0.33123 C_err=-0.036 | xImprE= 0.33475 C_err=-0.010
t=0.80, x_exact= 0.35749 | xEul= 0.35338 C_err=-0.041 | xImprE= 0.35737 C_err=-0.012
t=0.90, x_exact= 0.38077 | xEul= 0.37623 C_err=-0.045 | xImprE= 0.38063 C_err=-0.013
t=1.00, x_exact= 0.40461 | xEul= 0.39970 C_err=-0.049 | xImprE= 0.40446 C_err=-0.015

N=20, h= 0.050

t=0.00, x_exact= 0.20000 | xEul= 0.20000 C_err= 0.000 | xImprE= 0.20000 C_err= 0.000
t=0.05, x_exact= 0.20812 | xEul= 0.20800 C_err=-0.002 | xImprE= 0.20812 C_err=-0.001
t=0.10, x_exact= 0.21648 | xEul= 0.21624 C_err=-0.005 | xImprE= 0.21648 C_err=-0.001
t=0.15, x_exact= 0.22508 | xEul= 0.22471 C_err=-0.007 | xImprE= 0.22508 C_err=-0.002
t=0.20, x_exact= 0.23392 | xEul= 0.23342 C_err=-0.010 | xImprE= 0.23392 C_err=-0.003
t=0.25, x_exact= 0.24300 | xEul= 0.24237 C_err=-0.013 | xImprE= 0.24299 C_err=-0.004
t=0.30, x_exact= 0.25232 | xEul= 0.25155 C_err=-0.015 | xImprE= 0.25231 C_err=-0.004
t=0.35, x_exact= 0.26187 | xEul= 0.26096 C_err=-0.018 | xImprE= 0.26185 C_err=-0.005
t=0.40, x_exact= 0.27164 | xEul= 0.27061 C_err=-0.021 | xImprE= 0.27163 C_err=-0.006
t=0.45, x_exact= 0.28165 | xEul= 0.28048 C_err=-0.023 | xImprE= 0.28163 C_err=-0.007
t=0.50, x_exact= 0.29188 | xEul= 0.29057 C_err=-0.026 | xImprE= 0.29186 C_err=-0.008
t=0.55, x_exact= 0.30232 | xEul= 0.30087 C_err=-0.029 | xImprE= 0.30230 C_err=-0.008
t=0.60, x_exact= 0.31296 | xEul= 0.31139 C_err=-0.031 | xImprE= 0.31294 C_err=-0.009
t=0.65, x_exact= 0.32381 | xEul= 0.32211 C_err=-0.034 | xImprE= 0.32379 C_err=-0.010
t=0.70, x_exact= 0.33486 | xEul= 0.33303 C_err=-0.037 | xImprE= 0.33483 C_err=-0.011
t=0.75, x_exact= 0.34608 | xEul= 0.34414 C_err=-0.039 | xImprE= 0.34606 C_err=-0.011
t=0.80, x_exact= 0.35749 | xEul= 0.35542 C_err=-0.041 | xImprE= 0.35745 C_err=-0.012
t=0.85, x_exact= 0.36905 | xEul= 0.36688 C_err=-0.043 | xImprE= 0.36902 C_err=-0.013
t=0.90, x_exact= 0.38077 | xEul= 0.37849 C_err=-0.046 | xImprE= 0.38073 C_err=-0.014
t=0.95, x_exact= 0.39262 | xEul= 0.39025 C_err=-0.047 | xImprE= 0.39259 C_err=-0.014
t=1.00, x_exact= 0.40461 | xEul= 0.40215 C_err=-0.049 | xImprE= 0.40457 C_err=-0.015
```

The error constants stay in the same range over all reasonable step sizes, for Euler the error is $C·h+O(h^2)$, for improved Euler $C·h^2+O(h^3)$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Exact solution is 
$$y = \frac{1}{1+4e^{-x}}$$
One step $h = 0.1$ gives exact $y(0.1) = 0.216480689$.

Euler method gives $0.216$

Improved Euler gives $0.2164672$

Problem in the original solution is a missing $(y_{n+1}^*)^2$ when calculating the $f^*$.